LTSpice not working
I am new to LTspice and I am wondering why my circuit in LTspice is not reading the correct values, pretty much everything in the circuit is wrong and I am unsure why. I just noted the voltage across the 7 V supply though, which is reading zero. Here is the wrong values. and here are the correct ones. 

You should label your circuit nodes before running the simulation so that the nodes indicated in the graph will correspond to node names shown in your schematic.

Did you label your nodes AFTER you began your simulation and probed the nodes?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your ground is only connected to the current source I1, not to R1 and R2. Notice that the wires cross but there is no dot indicating a connection.

Here is your circuit with the correct answer. You can use DC operating point rather than transient analysis, but the latter will work too.

Using node numbers is not a great idea- we can't see where they are, and they can change when you edit the circuit.
